# How to create Xamarin chatbot that doesn't use Bot Framework

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, chatbot

I'm creating an app in Xamarin.Forms and I'd like it to have a chatbot feature. After searching online I've seen a lot of solutions that use Microsoft Bot Framework or Azure Bot Services but I do not want to use these due to not having a paid account. I'd like to know if there's any alternative way to create a chatbot with Xamarin?

Comment: google "free chatbot api".  SO is not the place to ask for recommendations for services, free or otherwise.

Comment: I'm not really looking for recommendations but rather anybody whose done it before and how they did it so that I can possibly replicate or get a clue. Trust me I've done my fair share of researching before asking here.

Comment: That is still not a good question for SO.  Please read [ask]

Comment: https://geekflare.com/chatbot-development-frameworks/ Dialogflow is C#

Comment: @ralfhtp Thank you, do you know of any helpful tutorials/articles on this?